# Is a break statement required or is the return statement enough?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, return, break

In my Python 3(.5) script I have a simple `for` loop, that looks like this:

```
request = "simple string"
ignore = (
  # Tuple that contains regex's to ignore
)
for (i, regex) in enumerate(ignore):
  if re.search(regex, request):
    print("Found regex {0}.".format(i))
    return False
```

Now, this works as expected and the loop stops on the first match that is found.
I understand that the `break` statement is what is used to break loops in Python.
Knowing this lead to the question: ***Must*** I use the `break` statement to break a loop or could I get away with using the `return` statement instead?

Keeping this question in mind, would it be better off for my code to look like this:

```
request = "simple string"
ignore = (
  # Tuple that contains regex's to ignore
)
for (i, regex) in enumerate(ignore):
  if re.search(regex, request):
    print("Found regex {0}.".format(i))
    break
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`return` exits a function immediately.

If you are in a loop, that breaks out of the loop and no `break` is required first.

So no, you are not required to use `break` if `return` suits your needs.

Comment: If he just use return in function, function will be return None. But if he don't use return function will be void. I prefer using break if I don't want to use function's output.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's important to remember that `return` will not exit function if expression to return throws an exception. You could for example put the return into `try` block and catch the exception without leaving the function. So it doesn't always exit function immediately.

Comment: @ihsancemil: there is no such thing as `void` in Python. When you don't use an explicit `return` the default is to return `None`.

Comment: @PeterNimroot: that's an edgecase, and the *exception* exits the block then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters As I said you can catch an exception and decide to simply `pass` it or do anything you wish with it - like `try: return 1 / 0; except: pass`. Also I wouldn't call it entirely an edge case, I've seen such technique being useful not once not twice in some low level projects.

Comment: @PeterNimroot: That still doesn't take away you require a `break` when a `return` will do. Sure you can alter the flow with an exception and then catch with `try`. You could use `return` in an except handler and raise an exception in a `finally` handler for even weirder interactions, but that's all very much beside the point here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree, I only wanted to point out that `return` doesn't always unconditionally exit function immediately as it is something that jabbed me in the past.

Comment: I use to add a short comment like `# possibly not reached` or similar right after the block with `return` inside. Just for the case you want to add more lines later.