# How to limit the size of a comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a `list` and want to build (via a comprehension) another list. I would like this new list to be limited in size, via a condition

The following code will fail:

```
a = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
b = [i for i in a if i == 1 and len(b) < 3]
```

with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compr.py", line 2, in <module>
    b = [i for i in a if i == 1 and len(b) < 3]
  File "compr.py", line 2, in <listcomp>
    b = [i for i in a if i == 1 and len(b) < 3]
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

because `b` is not defined **yet** at the time the comprehension is built.

**Is there a way to limit the size of the new list at build time?**

Note: I could break the comprehension into a `for` loop with the proper `break` when a counter is reached but I would like to know if there is a mechanism which uses a comprehension.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use a generator expression to do the filtering, then use `islice()` to limit the number of iterations:

```
from itertools import islice

filtered = (i for i in a if i == 1)
b = list(islice(filtered, 3))
```

This ensures you don't do more work than you have to to produce those 3 elements.

Note that there is no point anymore in using a list comprehension here; a list comprehension can't be broken out of, you are locked into iterating to the end.

Comment: `[1/i for i in range(-5, 5)]` does break out and doesn't iterate to the end.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: it raises an exception, that's *not the same thing* as a `break` statement. In the end, you have no list result at all.

Comment: Wasn't clear to me that you meant the `break` statement, that word can be understood in a more general way. [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38675546/1672429) not long ago you said *"[`return`] breaks out of the loop"*. In any case, the iteration doesn't go to the end. Also, not having a list result doesn't even have to be a problem. Consider `reciprocals = [1/x for x in a]`, I think that's reasonable code and if `a` contains a zero then one might want a `ZeroDivisionError` and not want a list.

Comment: This is a question about how to limit the size of the list produced by a list comprehension, though. That implies you *still want a list result*.

Answer (score 6):

[@Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42393595/5393381) is completly right that `itertools.islice` is the best way to solve this. However if you don't mind an additional (external) library you can use [`iteration_utilities`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which wraps a lot of these `itertools` and their applications (and some additional ones). It could make this a bit easier, at least if you like functional programming:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import Iterable

>>> Iterable([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]).filter((1).__eq__)[:2].as_list()
[1, 1]

>>> (Iterable([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])
...          .filter((1).__eq__)   # like "if item == 1"
...          [:2]                  # like "islice(iterable, 2)"
...          .as_list())           # like "list(iterable)"
[1, 1]
```

The [`iteration_utilities.Iterable`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/Iterable.html) class uses generators internally so it will only process as many items as neccessary until you call any of the `as_*` (or `get_*`) -methods.

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of [the `iteration_utilities` library](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities).</sup>

Comment: This is a very nice library, thanks (still reading the docs to get a grasp on the multitude of functions)

Comment: Might I recommend changing the first link to the project's home page: http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?

Comment: Note that using `(1).__eq__` means you'll get unpleasant results like `1.5` comparing equal to `1`, or `'potato'` comparing equal to `1`, because `NotImplemented` is considered true in a boolean context. (They added a DeprecationWarning for this a few years back, but DeprecationWarning is suppressed by default outside of `__main__`.)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `itertools.count` to generate a counter and `itertools.takewhile` to stop the iterating over a generator when the counter reaches the desired integer (`3` in this case):

```
from itertools import count, takewhile
c = count()
b = list(takewhile(lambda x: next(c) < 3, (i for i in a if i == 1)))
```

Or a similar idea building a construct to raise `StopIteration` to terminate the generator. That is the closest you'll get to your original idea of [breaking the list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9572933/6260170), but I would not recommend it as best practice:

```
c = count()
b = list(i if next(c) < 3 else next(iter([])) for i in a if i == 1)
```

Examples:

```
>>> a = [1,2,1,4,1,1,1,1]

>>> c = count()
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x: next(c) < 3, (i for i in a if i == 1)))
[1, 1, 1]

>>> c = count()
>>> list(i if next(c) < 3 else next(iter([])) for i in a if i == 1)
[1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: What advantage over the other answers does this have?

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't think it's better than Martijn's solution for this exact purpose, but it's more generalisable because the conditions for terminating the generator could be anything, not just a counter. Also the OP asked specifically about a list comprehension and this is the closest valid syntax to that

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks. Since you posted this well after the other answers, you might want to work something about the flexibility advantage into your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Same solution just without `islice`:

```
filtered = (i for i in a if i == 1)
b = [filtered.next() for j in range(3)]
```

BTW, pay attention if the generator is empty or if it has less than 3 - you'll get **StopIteration Exception**.

To prevent that, you may want to use next() with default value. For example:

```
b = [next(filtered, None) for j in range(3)]
```

And if you don't want 'None' in your list:

```
b = [i for i in b if i is not None]
```

Comment: Much better!!! thanks for showing how to do it without islice

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is the natural way to extract *n* items from a generator.

But you can also implement this yourself using a helper function. Just like the `itertools.slice` [pseudo-code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), we catch `StopIteration` to limit the number of items yielded.

This is more adaptable because it allows you to specify logic if *n* is greater than the number of items in your generator.

```
def take_n(gen, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        try:
            yield next(gen)
        except StopIteration:
            break

g = (i**2 for i in range(5))
res = list(take_n(g, 20))

print(res)

[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

b = [i for i in a if i == 1][:2]
```

I think this creates a full list comprehension (evaluating each element in the original list) and then slices it. It probably won't have a great performance in a long list, but is easy to read, and very fast to write.

Comment: The question was *Is there a way to limit the size of the new list **at build time**?* (note the emphasis - so the intent is to stop during the iteration, not after)

Comment: I agree, that's not building time, so my answer can be deleted

Comment: It's not build time

Answer (score -4):

use enumerate:

```
b = [n for i,n in enumerate(a) if n==1 and i<3]
```

Comment: That's simply wrong. First, this will discard everything except the first 3 items of `a` (the question wanted to limit `b` not `a`) and it will process the whole iterable. It won't stop after finding the third item. It just discards everything thereafter (however it will stick check the `n==1 and i < 3`).