# Reordering and slicing a numpy array using another array

Tags: python, numpy

Given two arrays, `arr1` and `arr2`, I want to extract from `arr1`, the first `cap` elements in the order it appears in `arr2`. So from the example below:

```
arr1 = np.array([3, 7, 1, 10, 2])
arr2 = np.array([0, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 6, 4])
cap = 3
```

From `arr1`, `3,7,1,2` appear in `arr2` ordered as `3,1,2,7`. I only want the first 3, so my desired outcome is `array([3, 1, 2])`.

I can get my desired outcome as follows:

```
ans = np.array([el for el in arr2 if el in arr1][:cap])
```

but this solution iterates over the entire `arr2` when I only want the first 3 occurrences. Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit the size of a comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393527/how-to-limit-the-size-of-a-comprehension)

Comment: If you are strongly concerned about performance, you might want to revisit my revised answer and have a look at Tom's adjusted plots to see how it performs in comparison to the alternatives. Apparently, the amended for-loop outpaces both your original list-comprehension as well as `np.isin()` in most scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt that doesn't use any iteration, and switches the membership checking to [`np.isin()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
>>> arr2[np.isin(arr2, arr1[np.isin(arr1, arr2)])][:cap]
array([3, 1, 2])
```

Since this is arguably harder to read than your list comprehension, here are the steps broken down:

```
# find elements of arr1 in arr2
subset_arr1 = arr1[np.isin(arr1, arr2)] # array([3, 7, 1, 2])

# find the elements of arr2 in subset1, this gets the desired order
subset_arr2 = arr2[np.isin(arr2, subset_arr1)] # array([3, 1, 2, 7])

# take the first cap elements
ans = subset_arr2[:cap] # array([3, 1, 2])
```

#### Timing

My original testing indicated my `np.isin()` approach to be the fastest.  However, [Georgy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16038459/georgy-kopshteyn) since updated their answer (the `for` loop) with a bug fix.  The new testing then **indicated Georgy's answer to be fastest for all tested data sizes**:

[image]

"np.isin" is my answer, "listcomp" is your original solution, "forloop" is the [other existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68105742/13386979).  In the above, the size of *N* (x-axis) is the length of `arr1`, `arr2` is double that length, and the `cap` is fixed at `5` (I thought this seemed reasonable, but see below for tweaks).

It seems the ability to stop early by the for loop can be very beneficial!  In my answer, the code has to check *all* elements of `arr1` for membership in `arr2` (`subset_arr1` above), and then *all* elements of `arr2` for membership in that subset.  Georgy's loop OTOH only has to check for membership of *some* of the elements of `arr2` in `arr1`.  So even though my looping should be faster, there can be much more of it!

The only parameter I tried fiddling with was the `cap`, which shows how smaller `cap` sizes are better for the for loop (smaller cap -> less iteration).  The above was `cap == 5`; with `cap == 100`:

[image]

And `cap == 1000`:

[image]

I reckon the other parameters could influence things as well (e.g. how likely it is for the is-in operation to return true AKA the range of numerical values, or the relative sizes of the two arrays).  I have made the [perfplot](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/) code below more parameterized if anyone wants to test - I'm tired of thinking about complexity :

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot

cap = 5
minnumber = 1
maxnumber = 10
factor1 = 1 # how size of arr1 relates to n
factor2 = 2 # how size of arr2 relates to n
low_n = 3
high_n = 18

def make_data(n):
    arr1 = np.random.randint(minnumber, maxnumber, n*factor1)
    arr2 = np.random.randint(minnumber, maxnumber, n*factor2)
    return arr1, arr2

def listcomp(arr1, arr2):
    return np.array([el for el in arr2 if el in arr1][:cap])

def npisin(arr1, arr2):
    return arr2[np.isin(arr2, arr1[np.isin(arr1, arr2)])][:cap]

def forloop(arr1, arr2):
    capcopy = cap
    lst=[]
    for el in arr2:
        if el in arr1:
            lst.append(el)
            capcopy -=1
        if capcopy <1:
            break
    return np.array(lst)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n : make_data(n),
    kernels = [
        lambda x: listcomp(*x),
        lambda x: npisin(*x),
        lambda x: forloop(*x),
        ],
    labels=['listcomp', 'np.isin', 'forloop'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(low_n, high_n)])
```

Comment: Great suggestion! I've slightly updated my for-loop, because in the old version the iteration did not actually stop after the cap has been reached but later matches have simply not been included. Would be interesting to know how this changes things.

Comment: @GeorgyKopshteyn your change is definitely warranted, and appears to be faster than mine for many cases!  +1.  See my thoughts above

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward iterative approach that stops after the `cap` has been reached:

```
lst=[]
for el in arr2:
    if el in arr1:
        lst.append(el)
        cap -=1
    if cap <1:
        break
ans = np.array(lst)
```