# Take exact number of inputs using list comprehension method on python

Tags: python, input, list-comprehension, multiple-input

I want to take exactly 20 int inputs from a user. How can I achieve that using the list comprehension? There is a way of setting the limit using a for loop in C and Java programming languages. But is there any workaround to achieve that in Python?

Below is the line of code to take multiple inputs from a user in Python. How can I set the limit here? Please note I want to take the input on the same line, separating them by hitting space.

```
int_list = [ int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]
```

Please note I am not asking to slice the list or number of iterations.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user enters a line containing fewer or more than twenty numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit the size of a comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393527/how-to-limit-the-size-of-a-comprehension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with enumerate:

```
int_list = [ int(x) for count,x in enumerate(input().split(" ")) if count < 20]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could index the list to take the first 20 items:

```python
int_list = [ int(x) for x in input().split(" ")[:20]]
```